# Bitbucket with Netlify CMS editorial Workflow

Tags: bitbucket, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I have a web app that is built in Gatsby and Netlify CMS with Bitbucket. Been looking for a way to implement editorial workflow in Netlify CMS. But seems that I cant make it work. Here's my code in my config.yml

```
backend:
  name: bitbucket
  repo: sample/repo
  branch: master
  auth_type: implicit
  commit_messages:
    create: 'Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    update: 'Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    delete: 'Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    uploadMedia: '[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”'
    deleteMedia: '[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”'

local_backend: true
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
```

I've hit a roadblock , I'm new to this kind of setup and researching about this in days. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you so much and God bless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [Netlify's docs](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#gitlab-and-bitbucket-editorial-workflow-support), the use in Bitbucket is still in beta, only available in version up to `2.10.6` (`netlify-cms`) or `2.11.3` (`netlify-cms-app`):

> `publish_mode: editorial_workflow`
>
> In order to track unpublished entries
> statuses the GitLab implementation uses merge requests labels and the
> BitBucket implementation uses pull requests comments.

In addition, when [dealing with Bitbucket](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/bitbucket-backend/#client-side-implicit-grant-bitbucket), you need to add the `app_id` in the `config.yml` (among the rest of configurations):

```
backend:
 name: bitbucket
 repo: owner-name/repo-name
 branch: default
 auth_type: implicit
 app_id: # The Key from your Bitbucket settings
 publish_mode: editorial_workflow
```

If your versions are up to date and the configuration properly set, you will see at the top of the screen the editorial workflow tab:

[image: Editorial workflow in Netlify]

The full workflow:

[image]

Keep in mind that the editorial workflow will only work in certain types of collections.

Comment: Follow up question sir. I have netlify-cms-app version 2.12.14. Does it need to be exactly those two version only? Thank you!

Comment: No, at least those versions but if you have a greater version it's also ok. These are the minimum required version.

Comment: Still it wont work. :( I've added the app_id and my netlify-cms-app version is greater.

Comment: `backend:
  name: bitbucket
  repo: sample/repo
  branch: master
  auth_type: implicit
  app_id: WWj4jwZ9DpHZUmRndE
  commit_messages:
    create: 'Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    update: 'Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    delete: 'Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    uploadMedia: '[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”'
    deleteMedia: '[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”'

# when using the default proxy server port
local_backend: true
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img`

Comment: "netlify-cli": "^3.4.7",
    "netlify-cms-app": "2.12.14",
    "netlify-cms-media-library-cloudinary": "^1.3.2",
    "netlify-cms-media-library-uploadcare": "^0.5.2",
    "netlify-cms-proxy-server": "^1.3.1",
    "netlify-cms-yoast-seo": "^1.0.5",

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Still the editorial workflow menu wont show. :(

Comment: Even if you create a post?

Comment: It wont work on a local server but when I tried to make changes to the live version it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!